# Upsampling 4d tensor in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I created a 4D tensor of the following size. (B, C, H, W)

And I want to reshape this tensor to the following size. (B, C, 2H, 2W)

Each value expands into 4 values, but only the elements in the original tensor that have an index corresponding to a value in the index tensor remain identical to the original tensor's value.

The index follows the following rule.

0 1

2 3

And here is an example below:

```py
original tensor:
torch.Size([1, 1, 2, 2])
tensor([[[[1.0000, 0.4000],
          [0.2000, 0.5000]]]])

index tensor:
torch.Size([1, 1, 2, 2])
tensor([[[[0, 2],
          [1, 1]]]])
```

```py
output tensor:
torch.Size([1, 1, 4, 4])
tensor([[[[1.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
          [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.4000, 0.0000],
          [0.0000, 0.2000, 0.0000, 0.5000],
          [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000]]]])
```

How can I efficiently transform this tensor while making good utility of GPU? (maybe we can use torch.tensor.scatter_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My initial thought was that you can utilize a [`nn.MaxUnpool2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MaxUnpool2d.html) layer to unpool the original tensor `x` at the desired locations from `index`. However, you current setup provides those indices locally using your based on your squared `0, 1, 2, 3` layout. This means that in order to effectively use an unpooling layer we first need to properly convert your current index tensor from this:

```
tensor([[[[0, 2],
          [1, 1]]]])
```

To something like:

```
tensor([[[[0,  6],
          [9, 11]]]])
```

Where each index refers to the location the moving window will place the values in `x`.

In order to do so we need to work on `index` by

1. First convert your index tensor to a one-hot encoding representation to expand the number of elements using [`nn.functional.one_hot`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.one_hot.html):

   ```
   >>> one_hot(index, 4)
   tensor([[[[[1, 0, 0, 0],      # [[[[[a0, a1, a2, a3],
              [0, 0, 1, 0]],     #     [b0, b1, b2, b3]],

             [[0, 1, 0, 0],      #    [[c0, c1, c2, c3],
              [0, 1, 0, 0]]]]])  #     [d0, d1, d2, d3]]]]]
   ```

   We then need convert the current tensor to the following layout:

   ```
   # [[[[[a0, a1, b0, b1],
   #     [a2, a3, b2, b3]],

   #    [[c0, c1, d0, d2],
   #     [c2, c3, d2, d3]]]]]
   ```
2. Begin by flattening viewing your tensor as a set of 2x2s:

   ```
   >>> ohe = one_hot(index, 4).view(2,2,2,2)
   tensor([[[[1, 0],     # [[[[a0, a1],
             [0, 0]],    #    [a2, a3]],

            [[0, 0],     #   [[b0, b1],
             [1, 0]]],   #    [b2, b3]],


           [[[0, 1],     #  [[[c0, c1],
             [0, 0]],    #   [[c2, c3]],

            [[0, 1],     #   [[d0, d1],
             [0, 0]]]])  #    [d2, d3]]]]
   ```
3. The series of steps taken now allow use to recover the desired layout without having to split and concatenate the elements. *You can look at a detailed explanation of the process on this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75530049/6331369)*.

   ```
   >>> y = ohe.transpose(-1,-2).reshape(2,-1,2).transpose(-1,-2)
   tensor([[[1, 0, 0, 0],      # [[[[[a0, a1, b0, b1],
            [0, 0, 1, 0]],     #     [a2, a3, b2, b3]],

           [[0, 1, 0, 1],      #    [[c0, c1, d0, d2],
            [0, 0, 0, 0]]])    #     [c2, c3, d2, d3]]]]]
   ```
4. Then flatten and unravel the indices by multiplying with an arrangement of values:

   ```
   >>> y.reshape(-1)
   tensor([ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0, 0])

   >>> i = y.reshape(-1)*(torch.arange(4*x.numel())+1)
   tensor([ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  7,  0,  0, 10,  0, 12,  0,  0,  0, 0])
   ```
5. The desired index tensor is:

   ```
   >>> unpool_i = i.nonzero().view_as(x)
   tensor([[[[ 0,  6],
             [ 9, 11]]]])
   ```
6. Finally you can apply the unpooling layer with:

   ```
   >>> unpool = nn.MaxUnpool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
   >>> unpool(x, unpool_i)
   tensor([[[[1.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
             [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.4000, 0.0000],
             [0.0000, 0.2000, 0.0000, 0.5000],
             [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000]]]])
   ```